# Boot2docker/Windows: can't run bash on Ubuntu container

Tags: windows, bash, docker, boot2docker

I'm working through "The Docker Book", am on chapter 3, installing and running an Ubuntu container.  I'm on Windows 7.1, using Boot2Docker.

Here's what happens when I try to run it (this is the second attempt, so it already has a local copy of the image):

```
$ docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
exec: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash": stat C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash: no such file or directory
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 5e985b0b101bb9584ea3e40355089a54d1fba29655d5a1e0900c9b32c4f7e4c4: [8] System error: exec: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash": stat C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

Status:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE           COMMAND                CREATED            STATUS              PORTS   NAMES
5e985b0b101b    ubuntu:latest   "C:/Program Files (x   21 minutes ago     loving_mayer
```

It's complaining about lack of C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash, but I certainly have that on my machine:

```
$ ls -l "c:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash"
-rwxr-xr-x    1 neilw    Administ   598016 May  4 09:27 c:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: When it complains about bash, it is the bash inside the Ubuntu image, not on you computer. Maybe you should download again the Ubuntu image, I have just tested on Windows, when I issue the same command as you, I get a prompt inside the container , not an error message

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This works for me:

```
docker run -t -i ubuntu //bin/bash
```

The double // avoids the conversion[1]

[1] http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, it's working now.  I normally use Cygwin, so MinGW idiosyncracies are still foreign to me.  That link is mighty useful.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem, but

```
docker run -t -i ubuntu
```

opens up a shell inside the image.

Comment: That works for me too, which is good to know.  However, I still need the original functionality to work correctly if I want to kick off a container with a specific command.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your host's shell is automatically expanding `/bin/bash` to  `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash` before it is passed to Docker, which isn't correct as obviously there isn't a `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash` inside the Ubuntu container.

Does using quotes fix the problem? For example:

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu "/bin/bash"
```

Comment: in boot2docker `docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash`  works fine, with this exact syntax

Comment: Yeah, it should at least (quotes have no effect btw).  When I do docker inspect on the container I just created, one line is "Path": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash".  When you run it and it works, what does inspect give for the path?